# Формирование списка месяцев в php

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли сделать список месяцев со смещением на следующий год?

Есть массив с месяцами:

```
$monthes = array(
    1 => 'Январь',    2 => 'Февраль',   3 => 'Март',     4 => 'Апрель',
    5 => 'Май',       6 => 'Июнь',      7 => 'Июль',     8 => 'Август',
    9 => 'Сентябрь',  10 => 'Октябрь',  11 => 'Ноябрь',  12 => 'Декабрь'
);
```

Пример списка в январе 2018:

```
Январь 2017
...
Декабрь 2017
```

Пример списка в феврале 2018:

```
Февраль 2017
...
Декабрь 2017
Январь 2018
```

В базе есть колонка с месяцем - month и с годом - year. Есть какая-то функция для получения списка месяцев:

```
function getMonthes() {
  global $monthes;

  foreach ($monthes as $id => $data) {

    $data .=  date(' Y');

    if($id < date('n')) {
      $ret .= "<option value='{$id}'>{$data}</option>";
    }

  }

  return $ret;
```

Comment: Так в чем затруднения то?

Comment: Не могу понять как это сделать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$months = array('Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май',  'Июнь', 
                'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь',  'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'
          );

$dateStr = date("Y-m-d"); // today
$begin = new DateTime($dateStr);
$end = (new DateTime($dateStr))->modify('+12 month');

$periods = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1M'), $end);

// вывод 
echo '<select>';
foreach($periods as $period){
    $num = $period->format("n");
    echo "<option value='{$period->format('Y')}'>{$months[$num - 1]}</option>";    
}
echo '</select>';
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5kb3-h2rv

---

**[DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php)** - Представляет временной период. Позволяет перемещаться в заданном временном интервале на равные промежутки времени. В данном случае это интервал от сегодня на год вперед (не включая последний месяц) с интервалом в месяц.

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentMonth = 4;
$currentYear = 2018;
for($i = 0 ; $i < 12; $i++){
    $m = ($i + $currentMonth) % 12 + 1;
    $y = (int) ($currentYear - 1 + ($i + $currentMonth) / 12);
    echo 'year: '.$y.' month: '.$monthes[$m];
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c28209300ecdf0d1312fb6fcb5e6815d17f4b8dd)

Comment: А можно сделать чтобы в прошлый год не возвращалось, например 2017 год и 11 месяц. Чтобы показывало от января 2017 до ноября 2017?

Comment: @DraXXX сделать можно всё, что угодно. Вы только определитесь с тем, чего хотите. В вопросе вы явно указали переход между годами. Да и самомуподумать никогда не мешает

Answer (score -1):

решила через стандартную функцию даты. Формат F возвращает полное название на английском.

```
$months = [];
for ($i=0; $i <= 12; $i++) { 
    $month = $i < 10 ? '0' . $i : $i;
    $months[$month] = date('F', strtotime('1970-' . $month . '-01'));
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]